# Unable to create read replica to aurora cluster using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to create read replica using the following command:

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica --db-instance-identifier dbname-read --source-db-instance-identifier dbname --availability-zone us-east-1c
```

I'm getting the following error:

> A client error (InvalidDBInstanceState) occurred when calling the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica operation: Automated backups are not enabled for this database instance. To enable automated backups, use ModifyDBInstance to set the backup retention period to a non-zero value.

I checked and the cluster is configured with automatic backups:

```
{
"DBInstances": [
    {
        "PubliclyAccessible": false, 
        "MasterUsername": "root", 
        "LicenseModel": "general-public-license", 
        "VpcSecurityGroups": [
            {
                "Status": "active", 
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg"
            }
        ], 
        "InstanceCreateTime": "2015-12-20T02:38:26.179Z", 
        "CopyTagsToSnapshot": false, 
        "OptionGroupMemberships": [
            {
                "Status": "in-sync", 
                "OptionGroupName": "default:aurora-5-6"
            }
        ], 
        "PendingModifiedValues": {}, 
        "Engine": "aurora", 
        "MultiAZ": false, 
        "DBSecurityGroups": [], 
        "DBParameterGroups": [
            {
                "DBParameterGroupName": "default.aurora5.6", 
                "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
            }
        ], 
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": true, 
        "PreferredBackupWindow": "03:44-04:14", 
        "DBSubnetGroup": {
            "Subnets": [
                {
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active", 
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet", 
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "us-east-1a"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "SubnetStatus": "Active", 
                    "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet", 
                    "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                        "Name": "us-east-1c"
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "DBSubnetGroupName": "dev-subnet-group", 
            "VpcId": "vpc", 
            "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "dev-subnet-group", 
            "SubnetGroupStatus": "Complete"
        }, 
        "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [], 
        "AllocatedStorage": 1, 
        *"BackupRetentionPeriod": 7,*
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "mon:10:11-mon:10:41", 
        "Endpoint": {
            "Port": 3306, 
            "Address": "dbname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        }, 
        "DBInstanceStatus": "available", 
        "EngineVersion": "5.6.10a", 
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a", 
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "dbname", 
        "StorageType": "aurora", 
        "DbiResourceId": "db-**********", 
        "CACertificateIdentifier": "rds-ca-2015", 
        "StorageEncrypted": false, 
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.r3.large", 
        "DbInstancePort": 0, 
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "dbname"
    }
]
```

}

Any idea?

Thanks,
Roey

Comment: Does the instance show that you currently have any backup snapshots?  Does this operation also fail if attempted in the console?

Comment: Yes, i can restore the instance from older backup snapshot. And no the operations isn't failing if i'm doing it from the console.

Comment: @RoeyAzroel did you get anywhere with this? Having the same issue.

Comment: @ffghfgh yes, the aurora engine doesn't support this api call (create-db-instance-read-replica), instead just create another instance in this cluster and he will be promoted to be read replica automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurora engine doesn't support

```
create-db-instance-read-replica
```

instead just creating another instance using

```
create-db-instance
```

with the option `--db-cluster-identifier`.

So the newly created instance will automatically sync with the writer/master will be promoted to read only automatically.

Comment: How do the new Instance acts as read replica? How do I add the data to it?